# Is it possible to access Service from an entry component

Tags: angular

I'm using an entry component that needs access to a service that is provided not at the root level, but at a feature module level. The service is currently provided in a root component. The entry component cannot access this service instance via DI in the entry component constructor. I have also tried providing the service via `providers` in the module, but also no luck. Is it possible to somehow gain access to a service instance in an entry component when the service is not at the root injector level?

E.g. a feature module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routing_Module } from './routing.module';

// Components
import { Feature_Root_Component } from './feature/feature.component';
import { Management_Component } from './feature/management.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Feature_Root_Component,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    Management_Component,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
})
export class Event_Module { }
```

There is a service currently being provided in `Feature_Root_Component`. I.e:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'feature-root',
  templateUrl: './feature.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./feature.component.scss'],
  providers: [Feature_Service],
})
export class Feature_Root_Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(private feature_service: Feature_Service) {}
}
```

Now when I try to access this service in the entry component constructor, I get a NullInjectorError. As a workaround, I instead pass the service as an input parameter to the entry component and access it that way. Though, this is very cumbersome and does not seem like a good implementation, as any nested components in the entry component must also have the service passed to them.

Comment: Is the feature module lazy loaded?

Comment: @AndreiGătej yes it is

Comment: Hm.. is the `Root Component` part of the `AppModule` ?

Comment: @AndreiGătej No it is part of the lazy loaded module. `Root` is probably not the best name here, but, it is the root component of the lazy loaded module.

Comment: might well post your project to Stackblitz and people can suggest better solutions when they have a look at the complete puzzle

Comment: @joyBlanks yes good point, I will have to create a reproduction of this soon

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Am I missing something? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-km1kgb?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffoo.service.ts

Comment: could you please provide a code where you render that component? I'm 99% sure the problem lies there

Comment: @AndreiGătej wow, that works perfectly. I think the difference must be in the implementation. You are adding the entry component `createComponent`. My implementation involves passing the entry component as a parameter to a modal service provided by a UI library. I do not know how this is implemented under the hood. However, [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjap6v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) is an example of the UI library I am using  (sorry only just discovered their stackblitz ). I will try to adapt your stackblitz to theirs and see if I can get it working. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @skwny glad it worked! good luck! :)

Comment: @Andrei see my last comment. The rendering is provided by the UI library I am using which may be the point of failure. There is a stackblitz link in my comment showing an example of the library use (but not trying to use a service - just an example of rendering the entry component).

Comment: I'm not sure what the main cause is, but after exploring a little bit, it might have something do to with this: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/overlay/overlay-ref.ts

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Entry Components are now deprecated, but since I am still on Angular 7 I think I can answer this.

Angular's definition of an Entry Component is [a bit broader than this](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components), but in your case let's say that an Entry Component is simply one that you create dynamically "via JavaScript" (as opposed to using statically it in some component's template).

In Angular you would use a Component Factory to create a component dynamically. Here's a basic example:

```
constructor(
  private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
  private injector: Injector,
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  // First you obtain an instance of the Component Factory for your entry component
  const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyEntryComponent);

  // You then use that factory to instantiate the component
  const layersComponent = factory.create(this.injector) as ComponentRef<MyEntryComponent>;

  // After this you can insert the component into the DOM, or do whatever with it
}
```

Notice here that the only required parameter to `factory.create()` is an instance of an Injector. An Injector is what defines the Dependency Injection scope of a Component, in other words - which Services (and other dependencies) the component will have access to.

In the above example I am using the same Injector, which the creating component uses. So any Services available (provided by) the creating component would also be available in MyEntryComponent. I am free to use a different Injector here too - I could use the Root Injector, for example (in which case MyEntryComponent would only have access to Services, which are `providedIn: 'root'`).

Now, a typical UI Dialog library will hide all of this away from you. Unfortunately, if they haven't exposed a way for you to provide an Injector instance, then you are likely out of luck. E.g. Angular's Material Dialog allows this, but a quick look at the docs of your UI Dialog lib suggests that there is no such functionality (although it seems that there were plans to include it, not sure if implemented: https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/4710).